# Jenkins: Any ideas on how to publish/report a directory built by the build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Our CI, if it succeeds, will place the installed for the build on a network drive that is backed-up.  The Jenkins build # is part of the directory name.

Any ideas on how to publish this network file path when the build finishes?  Would be nice if users could click on the link or ctrl click on the link to open up that folder.

This would be for a Window environment...

Answer (score 0):

The "[Publish over CIFS plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)" works quite well. I've used it myself.

It provides "Send build artifacts to a windows share (CIFS/SMB/samba)" functionality. Each server configuration can be tested with the "Test Configuration" button.

Comment: I just need to publish: \\us.company.com\qa\published_builds\project_foo\build_423  where 423 = the # of the Jenkins build that just ran on the Jenkins report page for the build.